# Schemathesis. Path parameter value from response of previous test

Tags: python, testing, yaml, openapi

I have to test my Open API 3.0 implementation for matching the YAML file using schemathesis.

I have to create a group by triggering URI **/group** which responds with created group id, which is further used in URI **/group/{group-id}** to access the group, for example, when doing HTTP DELETE.

In schemathesis documentation I read that I can use state machine and **add_link()** to access previous tests responses for further usage.

Here is the Python code:

```py
import schemathesis

schema = schemathesis.from_path("./Groups.yaml", base_url="http://127.0.0.1:8033/api/v1/groups")

schema.add_link(
    source=schema["/class/{class}/group"]["POST"],
    target=schema["/class/{class}/group/{group-id}"]["DELETE"],
    status_code="201",
    parameters={
        "group-id": "$response.body#/id"
    },
)

api = schema.as_state_machine()
TestCase = api.TestCase
```

I receive a success response on POST, but there are no DELETE requests with received **id** in URI.

UPD: Links declaration in yaml

```
 links:  
   patchGroupById:  
     operationId: patchGroup  
     parameters:  
       group-id: '$response.body#/id'
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Could you, please share the API schema portions relevant to the source & target endpoints? It might be the case for this issue - https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis/issues/823

Comment: @Stranger6667 unfortunately, I can't. When I declare links inside YAML file and execute schemathesis with CLI, everything works. But when I do it in python - it doesn't, whether I specify links with ***add_link()*** or in YAML file.

Comment: How do you declare links in the YAML file, so we can compare both ways? In Schemathesis, CLI and Python API use different machinery under the hood. Also, please,  share the Schemathesis version - there were some minor changes to this aspect in 3.9.7.

Comment: @Stranger6667
I suppose I used 3.9.7 version. Cant tell you exactly, I just did pip install, which is supposed to install the last one. And just recently I switched to 3.0.0 because I suspected the version.

Attached the yaml links declaration to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not immediately clear to me why those link definitions don't work as it highly depends on the schema definition. I'd suggest pinging me on Schemathesis's gitter & consider sharing the schema parts there in private.

Comment: @Stranger6667, sadly, there is no way, I can share the API doc. Decided to define links in the file directly and use the CLI tool. Works just fine. Thank you for an attempt to help.